# Django user profile query

Tags: django, django-profiles

I have been struggling to see what is wrong with this code for couple hours now. The project i m working on calls for users to register to the sites (taken care of by [Django registration plugin](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration).) Once registered, users will be able to add their company (name, address, phone etc...) to the site as a listing. So company has its own model. I am using Django profiles to show user info and company info on Django profiles page. Profiles also built on top of [Django Profiles plugin](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles).

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),    
url(r'^admin_export/', include("admin_export.urls")),   
url(r'^profiles/edit', 'profiles.views.edit_profile'),
url(r'^profiles/create', 'profiles.views.create_profile'),
url(r'^profiles/', include('profiles.urls')),
url(r'^profiles/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'profiles.views.profile_detail',name='UserProfileView'),
url(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls'))


#models.py

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,unique=True)
    #email = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    # Other fields here
    #company = models.ForeignKey(Company,blank=True,null=True)    
    #office = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username




class Company(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=True, blank=True)
    comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    comp_address = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    comp_email = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    comp_zip = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    comp_phone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    comp_city = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    #comp_state = models.USStateField(blank=True, null=True
    comp_state = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2)
    compwebsite = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    twitterurl = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    facebookurl = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.comp_name

class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=UserProfile
        exclude=('user',)

#views.py
def UserProfileView(request, username):
    context_dict = {}
    usercompany =  get_object_or_404(Company, user=userprofile)
    context_dict = {'usercompany': usercompany}
    return render_to_response('profile_detail.html', context_dict, RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: This might be easier with a bit more information about what doesn't work. Do you get an error ?

Comment: No errors, but i am not able to render Company info on profile pages. See views.py at the bottom. What my goal is to render company info that is submitted by the current logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userprofile` is actually not available when it's referenced in your views.py, so it should raise `NameError`

If I understood you right, the way to achieve this is:

```
#views.py
def UserProfileView(request):
    context_dict = {}
    usercompany =  get_object_or_404(Company, userprofile__user=request.user)
    context_dict = {'usercompany': usercompany}
    return render_to_response('profile_detail.html', context_dict, RequestContext(request))
```